# How to convert to master detail from single view controller

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail

I have developed an application in swift using single view template and sent it to apple for review. It has been rejected for a few reasons (no problem at all, it was my first try) Now I would like to convert it to master detail template so that it's going to be better for a universal application.
How can I convert it?

Comment: Start xCode, create a new project, and copy everything there from the old one.

Comment: What was the reason it was rejected ?

Comment: I know that there are no button for that, I just wonder I should ad split view and if required other stuff.

Comment: rejection reasons was not having restore purchases (actually it wasn't needed because of cloud integrity) and ipad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drag & drop split view controller from the Object library so your application will have master detail view controller template